# Which soccer players have been selected best player of the Copa América more than once?

Tags: football, statistics, copa-america

I know that Lionel Messi and Enzo Francescoli have been chosen the best player of the Copa América twice. It happened in 2021, 2015, 1995 and 1983 respectively. Are there other soccer players who have been chosen the best player of the Copa América more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the tournament was renamed Copa America in 1975. It isn't really hard to list all the best players:

| Year | Best Player |
| --- | --- |
| [1975](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1975_Copa_Am%C3%A9rica) | [image: Peru] [Teófilo Cubillas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Te%C3%B3filo_Cubillas) |
| [1979](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1979_Copa_Am%C3%A9rica) | [image: Chile] [Carlos Caszely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlos_Caszely) |
| [1983](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1983_Copa_Am%C3%A9rica) | [image: Uruguay] [**Enzo Francescoli**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enzo_Francescoli) |
| [1987](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1987_Copa_Am%C3%A9rica) | [image: Colombia] [Carlos Valderrama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlos_Valderrama) |
| [1989](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1989_Copa_Am%C3%A9rica) | [image: Uruguay] [Rubén Sosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rub%C3%A9n_Sosa) |
| [1991](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1991_Copa_Am%C3%A9rica) | [image: Argentina] [Leonardo Rodríguez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_Rodr%C3%ADguez) |
| [1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_Copa_Am%C3%A9rica) | [image: Argentina] [Sergio Goycochea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergio_Goycochea) |
| [1995](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995_Copa_Am%C3%A9rica) | [image: Uruguay] [**Enzo Francescoli**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enzo_Francescoli) |
| [1997](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1997_Copa_Am%C3%A9rica) | [image: Brazil] [Ronaldo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronaldo_(Brazilian_footballer)) |
| [1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1999_Copa_Am%C3%A9rica) | [image: Brazil] [Rivaldo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rivaldo) |
| [2001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001_Copa_Am%C3%A9rica) | [image: Honduraas] [Amado Guevara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amado_Guevara) |
| [2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_Copa_Am%C3%A9rica) | [image: Brazil] [Adriano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adriano_(footballer,_born_February_1982)) |
| [2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007_Copa_Am%C3%A9rica) | [image: Brazil] [Robinho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinho) |
| [2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_Copa_Am%C3%A9rica) | [image: Uruguay] [Luis Suárez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luis_Su%C3%A1rez) |
| [2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Copa_Am%C3%A9rica) | [image: Argentina] [**Lionel Messi**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Messi) |
| [2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copa_Am%C3%A9rica_Centenario) | [image: Chile] [Alexis Sánchez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexis_S%C3%A1nchez) |
| [2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_Copa_Am%C3%A9rica) | [image: Brazil] [Dani Alves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dani_Alves) |
| [2021](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_Copa_Am%C3%A9rica) | [image: Argentina] [**Lionel Messi**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Messi) |

If you want to count the best players of the South American Championship (before 1975), then [the full list of them is available on the RSSSF website](http://www.rsssf.com/tabless/sachampfulltrivia.html#best-players). According to this list two other players won the award twice:
[José Nasazzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Nasazzi) (Uruguay, 1923, 1935) and [Manuel Seoane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manuel_Seoane) (Argentina, 1925, 1927).

Comment: Not sure, supposedly Pelé was the best player of the 1959 Copa América.

Comment: @Pablo Hmm, interesting. It seems I'll need to dig deeper. At least, this list is a start. :)

Comment: that's why I upvoted

Comment: @Pablo I've updated my answer with the link to a full list of best players, including South American Championship.